# how to change the point format for drill down in pie charts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, pie-chart

I am using a pie chart with drill down, is there any way to change the point format in tool-tip function. I want to display; first pie chart in Percentage(%) format, and then drill down data in Metric Ton (MT)format.

I am getting the data in respective formats from the back end service. Products are coming in metric Tons and remaining-percentage, actual percentage are coming in percentage.

**My pie chart code is given below.**

```
function visitorData(data){
    var products = data.products;
    var remainingPercentage=data.remainingPercentage;
     var actualPercentage=data.actualPercentage
    Highcharts.chart('current', {
         credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Production report of current quarter'
        },
        subtitle: {

        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Planned Production',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Remaining Production Qty. ',
                y: data.remainingPercentage,
            },
             {
                name: 'Actual Production Qty.',
                y: data.actualPercentage,
                drilldown: 'ap'
            }
            ]
        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: [{
                name: 'production report',
                id: 'po',
                data: [

                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Actual Production Qty.',
                id: 'ap',
                data: data.products

            }  ]
        }
    }); 

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to solve this is to appoint a `tooltip: {pointFormatter: }` to your first level series. This will override the main `tooltip` formatter and show you the data you want it to show.

```
// Create the chart
 Highcharts.chart('container', {
         credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Production report of current quarter'
        },
        subtitle: {

        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
             //MT format for the lower drilldowns
             pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}MT</b> of total<br/>' 
        },
        series: [{
         tooltip: {
            //Pointformat for the percentage series
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>' 
        },
            name: 'Planned Production',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Remaining Production Qty. ',
                y: 3,
            },
             {
                name: 'Actual Production Qty.',
                y: 5,
                drilldown: 'ap'
            }
            ]
        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: [{
                name: 'production report',
                id: 'po',
                data: [1]
            }, {
                name: 'Actual Production Qty.',
                id: 'ap',
                data: [2]

            },


            ]
        }
    });
```

The reason why I opted to let the first level override the tooltip is because of the construction of your drilldown, and I figure all of those drilldowns will use the same tooltip format.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tLtoLbzu/) you can find a working JSFiddle.